# My FB application has been removed

Tags: facebook

This morning my facebook app has been removed and I don't know who has removed my application.

I received 3 e-mails tonight:

The first one:
App settings for MeteoSmit - Previsioni meteo (app id = 113007212065365) changed by API from 10.66.138.54 on Mon, 10 Dec 2012 14:48:06 -0800
Changed settings:
Old Value   New Value
canvas_page_url meteosmit

2nd:
App settings for MeteoSmit - Previsioni meteo (app id = 113007212065365) changed by Cullen Walsh from 10.171.32.25 on Mon, 10 Dec 2012 15:01:57 -0800

Changed settings:
Old Value   New Value
canvas_page_url     meteosmit

3rd:
App settings for MeteoSmit - Previsioni meteo (app id = 113007212065365) changed by API from 10.171.31.43 on Mon, 10 Dec 2012 15:03:50 -0800

Changed settings:
Old Value   New Value
canvas_page_url meteosmit

Who is Cullen Walsh?? a Facebook admin User or an hacker?

Thanks in advance.

Stefano b.

Comment: It seems like the same guy, Cullen Walsh, has removed our application "Marketland" too (APP ID: 186712578038225).

He also changed some quest adjustments in our Open Graph settings and the admins of the application can not access their own FB accounts, we receive a "locked account" error.

Comment: Seems to be a Software Engineer at Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/ckwalsh

Comment: Hi guys, this page might help!
https://www.facebook.com/help/155308851202619/

Answer (score 1):

It must be removed by the facebook admin team, no one else.